# Usage of \B{D} in T4

Tags: fonts

I started using the symbol generated by \B{D} from encoding T4. However, for uploading on arXiv, we are not allowed to use such an encoding. Is there an equivalent way to create this symbol without using T4?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

x \B{D} y
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will change the question accordingly - sorry for the badly posed question.

Comment: Is it supposed to be the letter eth?

Comment: @JosephWright - it does look like a capital eth (after checking it on Wikipedia), but I don't know for certain. However, I would like to know more generally if there is a way of porting specific characters/ symbols from the T4 encoding without actually loading it.

Comment: @user12588 The only fonts available in T4 encoding are bitmap. I believe this is the reason why arXiv rejects them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only available T4 encoded fonts are bitmap. So they're not really good for high quality typesetting, unless produced at a very high resolution. But I believe it's because of them being bitmap that arXiv rejects them.

If you really need the slanted bar, you can use the slash used in OT1 encoding for ł and Ł. The amount of kerning might be different for other fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% just to check

\DeclareRobustCommand{\BD}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \kern0.03em % move a bit right
    \fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\symbol{`\ }% lslashslash
  }%
  D%
}

\begin{document}

x \BD\ y

x D y

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the sloped bar, or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

x \DJ\ y
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great  (although I would have to check if arXiv is OK with this). As I mentioned above, I would also like to know more generally if there is a way of porting specific characters/ symbols from the T4 encoding without actually loading it.

Comment: @user12588 that is the font used in the majority of latex documents, using a macro defined in the format not a package, it is imposible for arxiv not to accept this.  Your final comment doesn't have an answer "porting" and "loading" means the same thing in this context. You either use a font or don't use it,you can't use it while not using it